# LED power usage and wiring

Tags: power-supply, led, home-automation

I'm a total beginner in electronics work and I have some questions.

I would like to fix an LED strip to the bottom of a [~2 m long IKEA shelf](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/lack-wall-shelf-white-50282182/). I would like two runs on the bottom (one at the back of the wall, one at the front), so ~4 m of LEDs in total. The LED type of choice is currently an SK6812 because it has a dedicated white LED, RGB, and each LED is addressable. I plan to control it with an ESP32, and power it with either a [Meanwell RS-100-5](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/MEAN-WELL/RS-100-5?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtRgJo%2FZ%2FMF7AkKuvSjhCpY) or a [Meanwell LPV-100-5](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/MEAN-WELL/LPV-100-5?qs=rBrhZj%252BuXXqUI2ddzBCmBA%3D%3D). These have been chosen based on: $$4\text{ m} \times 30\text{ LEDs per meter} \times 60\text{ mA} = 7200\text{ mA}$$

... so I need at least a 10 A power supply.

1. I'm concerned about working with mains power right off the bat - is there a power supply that has a standard plug that I could use instead of having to wire it myself?
2. What gauge of wire would I need to connect the LEDs to the power supply?
3. Are the PSUs overkill? They seem to be able to deliver a really high wattage compared to the [actual usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5HQj.png) measured [by The Hook Up on YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnvircC22hU).

Comment: Those 300mW (60mA) per LED are when all four channels (R, G, B and White) are set to maximum power. In your case that would mean 36W of LED-Light. 36W might not sound like much but the brightness would be like a 300W halogen Lamp. You probably would not want that much light. So you'll probably be good with much less. It's up to you.

Comment: Keep in mind that the conductors on the strip are relatively thin. Don't connect the two strips in resies but connect both ends of each strip to the +5V supply. Otherwise the voltage drop for the LEDs at the far end of the strip might prevent them from working in high load situations. (and don't run the LEDs at high power while they are on the reel)

Comment: @kruemi Thanks for the info! That indeed sounds like a _lot_ of light! I might just run a single 2m run first and see if it is enough. If I end up using two runs, how would I go about splitting the 5v output from the power supply? Thanks!

Comment: You can really just connect all the 0V (GND) with each other with wire and all the +5V together.

Comment: That type of LED chip consume full current only at maximum brightness. Current varies from 1mA to 60, depends on data. I used once 5V 2A supply for 300 pieces.

Comment: Full brightness is freakin’ bright! For indoor it will be unlikely you run the leds at full.if you use WLED code for the esp32, you can set the max brightness and it will ensure it doesn’t exceed it.  For the power supply you should be able to use a wall wart style like for a raspberry pi. These are 4A or so. No need to mess with mains wiring.